# How to get synonyms working in elastic search through C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, filter, analyzer

For the last few hours I've been trying to get the synonyms working in `Elastic Search` but so far failed. 
When I do the search it's like the synonyms never get indexed.

Below is the part of code where I think I may be making a mistake.
Please have a look and any help will be much appreciated.

```
var createIndexTask = Client.CreateIndexAsync(synonymsindexname, i => i
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                .Synonym("my_synonym", sf => sf
                    .Format(SynonymFormat.Solr)
                    .SynonymsPath("synonyms/solrsynonyms.txt")
                )
            )
            .Analyzers(an => an
                .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("standard")
                    .Filters("lowercase", "stop", "my_synonym")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<ClinicalCode>(c => c
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Completion(comp => comp
                    .Contexts(ctx => ctx
                        .Category(csug => csug
                            .Name("ShortDescription")
                            .Path(x => x.ShortDescription)
                        )
                    )
                    .Name(n => n.Suggests)
                    .Analyzer("simple") 
                )
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.LongDescription)
                    .Analyzer("my_analyzer") 
                    .CopyTo(ct => ct
                        .Field("allFields")
                    )
                )
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.ShortDescription)
                    .Analyzer("my_analyzer") 
                    .CopyTo(ct => ct
                        .Field("allFields")
                    )
                )
                .Text(t => t
                    .Name(n => n.ICDCode)
                    .Analyzer("my_analyzer") 
                    .CopyTo(ct => ct
                        .Field("allFields")
                    )
                )
                .Keyword(k => k
                    .Name(n => n.ICDCode)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Your code has large swatches of unnecessary whitespace (i.e. lots of contiguous blank lines). This makes it hard to read.

Comment: thanks @BDL for the edit, code should be easier to read now.